# Flatten nested object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

Im using Typescript and I have this object structure:

```
    {
  a: "somedata",
  b: "somedata2",
  c: [
    {
      name: "item1",
      property1: "foo",
      property2: "bar",
      property3:{property4:"baz",property5:"foo2"},
      property6:"bar2"
    },
    { name: "item2", properties:{...} },
  ]
};
```

I need to set the properties of every item on the same level in order to have my final object like this:

```
 {
  a: "somedata",
  b: "somedata2",
  c: [
    {
      name: "item1",
      property1: "foo",
      property2: "bar",
      property4:"baz",
      property5:"foo2",
      property6:"bar2"
    },
    { name: "item2",
      property1:"...",
      property2:"..." },
  ]
};
```

**EDIT:**
This is the only thing I have by now:

```
  getFinalObject(objectId){
    
        return this.http.get(
            this.API_URL + "/object/"+objectId,
            this.getHeaders()
          ).pipe(
            map((res:any) =>{//my final object should be mapped here
});
    }
```

Comment: Can the `properties` object have its own `properties` object? How deep can the nested objects get (infinitely deep?)

Comment: Please show us the code you tried

Comment: My properties object could have up to 2 more levels of depth inside (nested objects), I need them all out in only one level.

Comment: can you give an example with more levels.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalized function that should work at all depths (unless you blow the call-stack with an excessively deep object).

```
const flatten = <T extends Record<string, any>>(value: T): Record<string, any> =>
    Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(value)
            .flatMap(([k, v]) =>
                typeof v === "object" && v !== null
                    ? (Array.isArray(v)
                        ? [[k, v.map(x => typeof x === "object" ? flatten(x) : x)]]
                        : Object.entries(flatten(v)))
                    : [[k, v]]))
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAUDXMEBcMARBCALYCmiyxANDngEZGkXVIIBM9juwRANp88ubKIl4wCKqwCWUSuQCMvSZIAOAJxAbKWqAE9lrAGYgQa9aO279RrqyYItV67lt6DhgMxEMMJ72hgAsTggAXvSBOl5GAKxmFjwwAL4M7nhB3gBs4Vo8IqLpRXgB0rIkCko8dDF2BnKUEP4w5iBEYACuADY9aWkZeAC6WKkA3FhYoJCwpj1IimBoMAA8ACowlAAeS3AQMABKlKBacKvQWnJgAOZ1CGCGAHxPABQAbgg9XZRE6wCURGOp3Ol2ud3wjyeaCeIgA8kwAFYnKAAOlMOnIAFEwFArs1XqVcAjkcA0ZRcfiIB8vj9-kSJOiFlAALIIDSvV6CADWdXew3+MIZ1iMehAphg7zQqHQxBASJRxBgADJlZKYABCGUwbp9YWZGAAfhgrwAglotAhDKi5BBzZbDB96QaXUaYIIeXzUeR2a9tjCYKLKOKYP6ZbL5aSoErjfNFhS-YKiNt-sNRq6DUQSSjURS8U1qXGoEsnf9nRmJEJPZK02WpjMyD1KKieiAbq8iyWaAgy0A)

Comment: I might have a go at properly preserving type for fun, but it's a somewhat more involved endeavour.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no further levels of nesting than given in your example, and nesting only happens in the key "c", the below code may be what you meant. Also, had to use the type "any" for declaring the object because of restrictions put forward by typescript while deletion and insertion.

```
let s:any =   {
  a: "somedata",
  b: "somedata2",
  c: [
    {
      name: "item1",
      property1: "foo",
      property2: "bar",
      property3:{property4:"baz",property5:"foo2"},
      property6:"bar2"
    },
    { name: "item2", 
      property1: "foo",
      property2: "bar",
      property3:{property4:"baz",property5:"foo2"},
      property6:"bar2"  
    },
  ]
};



for(let i:number=0; i<s.c.length; i++) {
    let KEYS:string[] = Object.keys(s.c[i]);
    let VALS:string[] = Object.values(s.c[i]);
    let tempKEYS:string[] = [];
    let tempVALS:string[] = [];
    for(let j:number=0; j<VALS.length; j++) {
        if(typeof VALS[j] === "object") {
            tempKEYS.push(...Object.keys(VALS[j]));
            tempVALS.push(...Object.values(VALS[j]));
            delete s.c[i][KEYS[j]];
        }
    }
    for(let j:number=0; j< tempKEYS.length;j++) {
        s.c[i][tempKEYS[j]] = tempVALS[j];
    }
}

console.log(s);
```

Another way would be to use an interface and create another new object, taking values from your current one. That way, the "any" type can be avoided.

```
interface Inner {
    [property : string] : string
}

interface Outer {
    a : string,
    b : string,
    c : Inner[]
}

let s:any =   {
  a: "somedata",
  b: "somedata2",
  c: [
    {
      name: "item1",
      property1: "foo",
      property2: "bar",
      property3:{property4:"baz",property5:"foo2"},
      property6:"bar2"
    },
    { name: "item2", 
      property1: "foo",
      property2: "bar",
      property3:{property4:"baz",property5:"foo2"},
      property6:"bar2"  
    },
  ]
};


let newS : Outer = {
    a : s.a,
    b : s.b,
    c : [] 
};



for(let i:number=0; i<s.c.length; i++) {
    newS.c.push({});
    let KEYS:string[] = Object.keys(s.c[i]);
    let VALS:string[] = Object.values(s.c[i]);
    console.log(VALS.length);
    for(let j:number=0; j<VALS.length; j++) {
        if(typeof VALS[j] === 'string') {
            newS.c[i][KEYS[j]] = VALS[j];
        }
        else if(typeof VALS[j] === 'object') {
            let innerKEYS : string[] = Object.keys(VALS[j]);
            let innerVALS : string[] = Object.values(VALS[j]);
            for(let k:number=0; k<innerKEYS.length; k++) {
                newS.c[i][innerKEYS[k]] = innerVALS[k];
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(newS);
```